# Connecting to SQL Server database from Windows on ARM64

Tags: python, sql-server, windows, arm, odbc

I'm using a Surface Pro X (2020), and attempting to connect to a remote SQL Server database. I have installed the ODBC drivers (which are x86 at this point, but installed fine under emulation). However, when I try and connect to a DSN, I get the following (connecting from Python with pyodbc):

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=<my dsn here>;Trusted_Connection=yes;Connection Timeout=60;")
```

> ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Is there a trick to getting things working?

Comment: If it cannot found your DSN, you probably create in in other odbcad32.exe than should be used. Why do you use x32 and not x64?

Comment: Its an ARM64 machine, and currently only has x32 emulation. I probably just have to wait for a native driver.